# Remove unique random items from array, then refill to restart the process?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var myArray = ['A','B','C'];
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    if (myArray.length > 0) {
      var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
      var b = myArray.splice(a, 1);
      document.getElementById("showRand").innerHTML = b[0];
    } else { 
      //restart
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
<div id="showRand"></div>
```

Onclick, it randomly emptying myArray, how to refill the array then repeat the process when myArray is empty?

Thanks for your help..

Comment: `else { myArray = ['A','B','C']; }`?

Comment: yup it works but im just wondering why it only restarts after clicking 2 times..

Comment: The first time you don't have any elements, you fall in the `else` and that re-initialises `myArray`. The next time you click, it goes in the `if` part. If you want to not click twice, then do the initialisation with `if (myArray.length === 0) {  myArray = ['A','B','C']; }` and don't add an `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myArray = ['A','B','C'];
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    if (myArray.length == 0) {
      myArray = ['A','B','C'];
    }
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    var b = myArray.splice(a, 1);
    document.getElementById("showRand").innerHTML = b[0];
}
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
<div id="showRand"></div>
```

Comment: hi sir, if it's not too much to ask, can u check why it's not working in keydown event? to test, enter a, b or c multiple times. thanks https://jsbin.com/cujagok/edit?js,output